# using Ionic 2 CLI with meteor backend

Tags: meteor, ionic-framework, ionic2, meteoric

Is there a way of using Ionic 2 CLI with meteor's server side?
I Ionic 1 we could use the meteor-client-side, any suggestion how to use it now ? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I've been running though the rigor of researching the same possibility, and I've come to conclusion, one would not want.

You've probably seen this [this tutorial](http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp/ionic/server) already.

Using that example, I had attempted to modify the Meteor CLI directly without success. I've decided instead to drive my build process from Gulp wrapping both Ionic CLI and Meteor CLI behind tasks. The mobile/web apps are separate from the Meteor server (as in the example). I've also abstracted the Meteor client only library behind an Angular/Redux service to give me the flexibility to even replace Meteor (with say something like Phoenix Framework or RethinkDB), and moved that service into an NPM  module.

Decoupling the client(s) and server implementation and using your own orchestrating build process may also give the added benefit to support more client profiles beyond what is supported by either CLI dependently as we have discovered.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
So , you are saying there's no actual solution for this at the moment right?

Comment: @ShaharLahav Yes, there's no actual off-the-shelf solution at this time as, but both CLI could easily be wrapped and orchestrated by Gulp task. I will be opening large portions of our code to demonstrate the various strategies I explored.

Comment: Actually if found a solution, I bundled Metoer-client-sode using angular2 And now I can use DDP connection to my meteor server.